# What does the JS "//= require bootstrap/" syntax mean? (Bootstrap 3 Sass)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, sass

### Version:

Bootstrap Sass v3.1.1.

### File:

Inside this file:

```
assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js
```

### Confusing Syntax:

There are a bunch of lines that look like so:

```
//= require bootstrap/affix
//= require bootstrap/alert
//= require bootstrap/button
...
```

I am unfamiliar with this syntax. I simply want to generate a minified version of all the bootstrap JS files.

**What does this syntax mean?** And, how is it used?

For context, my goal is simply to use Bootstrap Sass in a way that makes upgrading to the latest future versions of BS as straight forward as possible.

Comment: A quick Google search returned https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#the-directive-processor...

Comment: @stevuu I don't understand how to use sprockets or what they're for. Are you saying this is using sprockets syntax? What is it?

Comment: Yes, for people who use Rails (or Sprockets separately). See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sprockets syntax. It compiles the JS into a single file Sprockets.

> Sprockets is a Ruby library for compiling and serving web assets. It features declarative dependency management for JavaScript and CSS assets, as well as a powerful preprocessor pipeline that allows you to write assets in languages like CoffeeScript, Sass and SCSS

Sprockets' repo: https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets
Sprockets in the Bootstrap Sass readme: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#javascript

information via @stevuu, found in comments on question above.